# Java iterator variable scope

Tags: java, iterator

Here's one part of the code I just wrote. Basically the class `Document` implements the `Iterable` interface. The iterator will iterate through the nodes like a linked list. In the `remove` method, I used the reference of `nodeMap`, which is in the `Document` class scope. However the `this` reference should refer to the `Iterator` itself so how come it could find that object? Or is the `Iterator` a child class of `Document`?

I haven't thought about this question before. Suddenly just made myself confused.

```
public class Document implements Iterable<DocumentNode> {
    Map<Integer, DocumentNode> nodeMap;

    public Iterator<DocumentNode> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<DocumentNode>() {
            DocumentNode node = nodeMap.get(0);

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return node != null && node.next != null; 
            }

            @Override
            public DocumentNode next() {
                if (node == null) {
                    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
                }
                return node.next;
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                if (node == null) {
                    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
                }
                if (node.prev != null) {
                    node.prev.next = node.next;
                }
                if (node.next != null) {
                    node.next.prev = node.prev;
                }
                nodeMap.remove(node.documentID);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean : How come that `nodeMap` is accessible in `Iterator` anonymous inner class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iterator is an instance of an anonymous inner class of the class `Document`. There are two kind of inner classes:

- the static inner classes are not attached to an instance of the outer class, they only have access to their own members and the static members of the outer class.
- the non-static inner classes own a reference to the instance of the outer class in the context of which they have been created, so they can access directly non-static members of the outer class. This is the kind of classes the iterator in your code is an instance of.